# Wildcard selectors in css path for grunt-contrib-compass

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm trying to use grunt-contrib-compass for an AngularJS project with multiple app folders. Here is my basic directory structure:

```
/root
   /appA
   /appB

   ...

   /appX
     /public
         /modules
             /moduleName
                 /css
                 /sass
```

gruntfile.js is stored in /root

My compass task is set up as follows:

```
compass: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            cssDir: 'app*/public/modules/**/css',
            sassDir: 'app*/public/modules/**/sass',
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        } 
    }
}
```

Note the wildcard selectors (*) in "cssDir" and "sassDir".

When this task runs, it successfully finds the .scss files in the directory specified for "sass". However, upon creating the .css files, it creates a new folder structure in /root like so:

```
/root
   /app*
       /public
           /modules
               /**
                 /css
```

The "css" folder is left empty and the actual .css file is saved in the same directory as my .scss files.

As an example, this is the terminal output for one of the .scss files when the compass task is run:

```
>> File "appStudentHousing/public/modules/studentHousingHome/sass/styles.scss" changed.
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
directory appStudentHousing/public/modules/studentHousingHome/sass
write appStudentHousing/public/modules/studentHousingHome/sass/styles.css (0.003s)
```

It appears that the task recognizes wildcard selectors in the "sassDir" option, but it does not recognize them in the "cssDir" option. It creates a blank folder structure with the asterisks in the actual folder name, and then for some reason it saves the output .css file in the same folder as the .scss file.

Thanks much for any insight you can provide.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you cannot using globbing patterns in the `cssDir` and `sassDir` options because the `Compass` `Grunt` plugin can only compile to one directory per given target.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still new to Grunt. What is the given target in this case?

Comment: Ah, no problem. The given target here is `dev`. `Grunt` always defines its tasks as the task itself, `compass` in this case, and multiple targets for the task. You could go ahead and define more targets besides `dev` (which also does not need to be called `dev` by the way). To call a specific target of a task you call it with `grunt task:target`. In your case `grunt compass:dev`. Simply running `grunt compass` also works here because you only have one target defined.

Comment: Okay, I get it now! I did not understand that was a target. So all I need to do is specify a different target for each `appX` folder, and then I can set up a unique `grunt-contrib-watch` task for each target with the sass/css folder paths defined explicitly -- no wildcards necessary.

Thank you so much Timusan. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it with the green checkmark.

Comment: More info on grunt targets: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets

Comment: Happy I could help. I have converted my comments (with a bit of extra explanation) into an answer. The basic workaround would indeed be to specify different targets for your directories, until the `compass` plugin supports multiple directory globbing. The `watch` plugin works exactly the same, indeed (it is actually functionality delivered by `Grunt`, so all plugins have the multiple target ability). You can specify different targets to "watch" and run the compilation automatically on file changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comments converted into an answer:

Currently, the `compass` `grunt` plugin can only process single directories per target, thus no globbing that would match with multiple directories.

To circumvent this limitation, you always have the ability to create mutiple `targets` inside your `compass` task (`Grunt` functionality). A `target` is a subdivision of a `task` and can be used to setup different execution scenarios.

Two different `targets` for the `compass` plugin could look something similar to this:

```js
compass: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            cssDir: 'app/dev/modules/css',
            sassDir: 'app/dev/modules/sass',
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        } 
    },
    live: {
        options: {
            cssDir: 'app/live/modules/css',
            sassDir: 'app/live/modules/sass',
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        } 
    }
}
```

This would give you two `targets`, `dev` and `live`, which specify different options. To execute each `target` individually, you simply call them on your command-line as follows:

```bash
$ grunt compass:dev
$ grunt compass:live
```

The naming of a `target` is totally up to you, there are no strict conventions to follow. If you have a single `target` for your `task`, then running the task like so:

```bash
$ grunt compass
```

Executes the single `target`. You do not need to explicitly specify it. However, if you have multiple `targets` in your `task`, then `Grunt` shall execute *all* of them in order when running with the above command.

And, as you have seen yourself, the [official `Grunt` documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) gives you more detailed info regarding `tasks` and `targets`.

Comment: Thanks Timusan!! You rawk! \m/